# Cannot Save Multiple Objects To DynamoDB?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to add multiple entries to my DynamoDB database through a service, but when the code is executed, Only one entry is saved. This is what I have done so far:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), // Context
            "us-east-1:851c121e-326d-4c9e-be47-fec40eb7b693", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

    AmazonDynamoDB client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Adding To Database...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), // Context
            "us-east-1:851c121e-326d-4c9e-be47-fec40eb7b693", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
    );

    AmazonDynamoDBClient ddbClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(cognitoProvider);

    DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(ddbClient);

    String streamName = intent.getStringExtra("streamName");
    String userCreated = intent.getStringExtra("userCreated");
    ArrayList<String> selectedFriend = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("userInvolved");
    intent.getStringExtra("comment");

    for(int i = 0; i < selectedFriend.size(); i++){

        Streams streams = new Streams();

        streams.setStreamname(streamName);
        streams.setUsercreated(userCreated);
        streams.setUserinvolved(selectedFriend.get(i));
        streams.setUnread(true);
        streams.setDeleted(false);

        mapper.save(streams);

    }
}
```

And like i said, only one entry will be saved. I was suggested to use an arraylist, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. Can anyone help?

All help is appreciated.

EDIT: The `Streams.java` class:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Streams")
public class Streams{

    private String streamname;
    private String usercreated;
    private String userinvolved;
    private boolean unread;
    private boolean deleted;

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Stream_Name")
    public String getStreamname() {
        return streamname;
    }

    public void setStreamname(String streamname) {
        this.streamname = streamname;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "User_Created")
    public String getUsercreated() {
        return usercreated;
    }

    public void setUsercreated(String usercreated) {
        this.usercreated = usercreated;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "User_Involved")
    public String getUserinvolved() {
        return userinvolved;
    }

    public void setUserinvolved(String userinvolved) {
        this.userinvolved = userinvolved;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Unread")
    public boolean isUnread() {
        return unread;
    }

    public void setUnread(boolean unread) {
        this.unread = unread;
    }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "Deleted")
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems your DynamoDB hash key is the `user created` field in the Stream class. This is the DynamoDB primary key which uniquely identifies a single item in the DynamoDB table.

Each time you call `mapper.save(streams)`, you are overwriting the item you wrote in the previous iteration of the loop since it seems you only set the `user created` field once here:

`String userCreated = intent.getStringExtra("userCreated");`.

Try using a unique identifier (e.g. `stream name` as the hash key). If multiple items have the same hash key you can also use a schema with a range key to create a (hash key, range key) primary key to uniquely identify an item in the DynamoDB table.

Answer (score 0):

DynamodbMapper has a batch save method that allows you to save multiple objects in a batch. Check out the [DynamoDBMapper.batchSave](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/DynamoDBMapper.html#batchSave(java.util.List)).